# How to send packets from one host to two different switches

Tags: mininet

I'm trying to create a topology in mininet with two hosts (h1, h2) and 4 switches (s1, s2, s2, s4). Every host is connected to two different switches and switches are connected to each other. Links:

s1 -- s3

s2 -- s4

h1 -- s1

h1 -- s2

h2 -- s3

h2 -- s4

I try to send the packet from h1 to h2 with two different paths.
One is h1 -- s1 -- s3 -- h2 and the other is h1 -- s2 -- s4 -- h2.
I want to send packets from one host to two different switches at the same time(for example from h1 to s1 and s2)

How can I send a packet from one host to two different switches using minimet?

Comment: How do you send a packet from one host to one switch in the first place?

Comment: I use ping to generate traffic.